# What are the criteria to get the Socratic badge?

Tags: support, badges

How is the **Socratic** badge awarded? I see the badge description as,

> Asked a well-received question on 100 separate days, and maintained a
>   positive question record. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

I have the **Inquisitive** badge which is a silver badge. It essentially is the same as **Socratic** with fewer number of days (30 days).

I have a positive question record for more than 100 questions (I have more than 100 questions that have a positive score on them). And am also sure that I asked these questions on separate days (may be 1 or 2 questions might be asked on the same day). But I still do not have the **Socratic** badge.

So, I believe it should have something to do with how well my questions were received.

What is a well-received question? Is it based on the number of views?

Also, is there a way to see how many more questions are needed for my **Socratic** badge?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ask 100 different Q's that are over the course of 100 unique days and have at least a +1 on said 100 Q's. This meta question titled: [Asking days badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234259/asking-days-badges) explains the well received as follows:

*excerpt*

> A well-received question is one that's open, not deleted, and has a
>   score > 0. If you ask at least one well-recieved question in a UTC day
>   and none of your questions that day are deleted, downvoted, or closed,
>   you get one more day of credit toward the badge. Whenever the badge
>   criteria is checked, previous asking days are re-evaluated so that
>   there's an incentive to fix downvoted and/or closed questions. The
>   no-deleted-questions criteria is to prevent people from asking several
>   questions at once and deleting any that aren't upvoted or answered to
>   ask another day. (Though this is a losing strategy in the long run.)

I highly suggest reading that meta question to get the full details.